# Is it possible to create a blob triggered azure function with a certain file name?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm using C# to create the trigger so I don't have an explicit function.json file

```
   [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("dev/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            if (name=="Test1.xlsx")
            {
                // Any Task that I need to do
            }      

        }
```

This runs successfully for me but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it, this method causes the function to be triggered for every file and then checks if it matches the criteria or not.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the question?

Comment: Why would you even need that? If you give a static path, how will the function trigger happen? I doubt if azure fn triggers on any content changes in the blob

Comment: have a look at the *Blob name patterns* in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#blob-name-patterns

Comment: @MandarDharmadhikari I require the function to get triggered when a certain file is submitted to the container

Comment: @Kamesh The path is just confined to the container where I need to extract the data from, could you elaborate on the part "static path"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could bind a certain file with the file, it will filter all files only the file specified name will trigger the function. Below is my test:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "test/abc123.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

I upload some file files only this one will trigger the function, so if you still have other errors or problem please provide more details or share your code.

[image]

**Update**:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("test/123.txt", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was what I was looking for.
Could you also help me to proceed with this in .NET since it doesn't have an explicit function.json where I can make these changes

Comment: @Akshat Gautam , you could try the code I have updated, it could work. And if  this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should configure the static path of the blob for which you want to trigger the function. For example: In below image the path is set to `container/file.csv`. So whenever there's a file with name `file.csv` in my blob container named `container`, the blob trigger will run.

[image]

This is my sample function code:

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob with Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

Since you are using .NET and not csx, the code for you will look like:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("container/file.csv", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob with Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

See it executes the function when I copy a file named `file.csv` to `container`. It does not trigger for any other files in any other containers. The complete path should match.

[image]

Also, every azure function has a function.json file and that is what is used to define binding parameters for the function. When using .NET, if you perform `dotnet build` and go and look into the bin folder of the build, you will see that a `function.json` is generated.

The only problem in your function code is that you have a second parameter `name`. This parameter is only required when you are defining a dynamic path in the function bindings which is not the case for you as you need a static predefined path. So try removing the second argument name and it should be working fine.